# I can't shutdown windows 10. and when booting up in specific cases i get a graphical error

Tags: linux, windows, boot, shutdown

So this started after installing antergos linux on my legacy bios machine (same hdd).
 When i shutdown windows it just goes to the log-in screen and if i try to shutdown it from the log-in screen, nothing happens.

Oh and when i shutdown the system by holding the power button then booting again **into windows** i get a graphical error(or a glitched image). the only way to fix this is to boot into antergos then **shutdown (restarting won't temp fix it)** after that i can boot into windows again.

Comment: What happens when you enter `shutdown /s /t 0` at the command prompt?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that shut down my system. maybe i can do a tiny cmd script for the time being if i didn't fix this. oh and the graphical error happened again. i went to grab my phone to take a picture for you but by the time i went to grab my phone the error was gone and my pc booted normally, looks like i was just impatient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have Windows [`Fast Startup`](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) enabled in Windows, which prevents clean shutdown. `Hibernate` may also need to be disabled. If either are enabled, there may be issues when dual-booting.

To disable `Fast Startup` in Windows:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `buttons`.
- Select `Change what the power buttons do`.

[image: Fast startup option]

- If the `Turn on fast startup` option is not available, enable it through `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.
- Clear the checkmark on`Turn on fast startup`.

To disable `Hibernate` using a script:

- Create a batch file with the following:

> powercfg -h off
>
> shutdown /s /t 0

- Make a shortcut to the .bat file, and in the `Advanced` dialog, set it to `Run as Administrator`.

There is a [tutorial](https://windowsreport.com/cant-disable-fast-startup/) if you have difficulty changing settings.

**N.B.** Microsoft may re-enable `Fast Startup` with some updates.